# Is there a Google Calendar Mac Desktop App?

Tags: macos, google-calendar

Is there a native OS X app that allows me to see my Google calendar?

Comment: Some modern web browsers support creating standalone web apps on the desktop. So just create one for calendar.google.com though your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Here's another way, adding Google Calendar as a Chrome App with standalone window. The calendar is then available in Launchpad and the Dock.

1. Navigate Chrome to your calendar URL, e.g https://calendar.google.com
2. Create Chrome App shortcut from the URL - *Chrome drop down menu (3 dots icon on top right) > More Tools > Create Shortcut*

[image: Open Chrome Drop Down menu]

[image: Create Chrome App Shortcut]

Note: check the "*Open as window*" box

[image: Create shortcut dialog]

3. Open the "*Google Calendar*" from Chrome Apps or Launchpad!

[image: Google Calendar from Launchpad]

4. Select "*Keep in Dock*" to keep the calendar icon in the MacOS Dock (optional)

[image: Add Calendar to Dock]

That's it! Your Google Calendar App is now available as a standalone window app from the MacOS Dock and Launchpad.

[image: Google Calendar App]

Comment: Note that this is a good answer but other apps eg fluid do this as well with similar steps

Comment: This is a great alternative to downloading another Mac app. Chrome shortcuts are awesome!

Comment: Even I prefer native apps, this is just great, thank you!

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that you can’t have multiple accounts with this solution. And in order to switch to another account, you will have to create a new Person in Chrome, then perform the steps above, and then upon opening the same shortcut, window with that other account’s calendar will load. To go back, you have to switch to Persona 1, and perform the same, but you won’t see both in the same time.

Comment: @SinišaŠašić It supports multiple accounts. To change google accounts, you need to click the account switcher / user icon in the top-right. It will then open the other account in Chrome. It will use the first logged in "default" google account by default for the calendar load.

Comment: @DavidThomas that is what is described in my previous comment, what you refer to as “switcher” is termed “Persona”(s) by Chrome. But I see that my opening sentence might have been unclear, the point is you can’t have them both *in the same time*, which is something e.g. Calendar.app for Mac can.

Comment: On Microsoft Edge, same thing except that the option is available under "Apps > Install this site as an App"

Comment: @rjurney I've installed latest Chrome Version 88.0.4324.146  and the menu option is still there. https://i.imgur.com/SvE0Snv.png

Comment: I was mistaken!

Comment: This just opens another chrome tab, not really the best solution

Comment: It doesn’t open a chrome tab, if you check “open as window”, it opens the calendar in its own special tab-less window (see screenshot)

Comment: This was genius!

Comment: Is there any way of setting this up so that the Chrome Browser doesn't open as a separate app at the same time? When I open the newly created Google Calendar app, both Chrome Browser and the Google Calendar app open (2 apps in the dock) - I only want the Google Calendar app, as I use the superior FireFox for a day to day browser.

Comment: I use this option, but I cannot get it to send alerts/notifications using the OS. Any thoughts? I have the experimental "Use Native Notifications" enabled, but nothing. Occasionally I see the app take focus, but more often than not, I miss it. Also annoying that it also opens an empty chrome window

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Safari and Mozilla?

Comment: has anyone figured out a way to enable push notifications for Chrome shortcuts? This would be the perfect solution

Comment: It is now located under "Save and Share" => "Create Shortcut"

Answer (score 95):

Yes, the built-in Calendar app lets you add them.

For your Mac:

1. On your computer, open Calendar
2. In the top left corner of your screen, click Calendar > Preferences.
3. Click the Accounts tab. On the left side of the Accounts tab, click +.
4. Select Google > Continue.
5. Enter your Gmail address, password, and verification code (if you have one).
6. Click Accept.
7. On the Accounts tab, choose how often you want Apple Calendar and Google Calendar to sync.

For more information, see https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358

Comment: Unfortunately you can't make changes, only view existing calendars and events.

Comment: If you want to add more calendars you have in your Google Account, go to the same account preferences and next to the tab `Account Information` select the tab `Delegation` and put a checkmark in all the calendars you want to import

Comment: Just download this app: http://dailypressgroup.org/apps/Google%20Calendar.zip , it is Google Calendar website wrapped with ElectronJS. Built with Nativefier (https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier)

Comment: If want to see "Other Calendars" you have also listed in your Google Calendar, got to https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect (per the more information link in the answer).

Comment: I want a material design.

Comment: This is not a Google Calendar application, this is Mac's calendar application.

Comment: @JamesTurner, I happen to be working with my Google Calendar from Mac desktop app for years now. There is a missing data point about your situation.

Comment: I don't understand why people vote for this answer. This is not what i want.

Answer (score 4):

I find the design of Apple's Calendar app frustrating on a number of levels, and also prefer not to have to context switch between the Google Calendar web UI and something else.

To solve this, I'm using [Fluid](https://fluidapp.com/), which wraps any URL in a native shell.

This lets me use all the features of the familiar Google Calendar while avoiding the problem of having my calendar constantly getting lost amongst my browser tabs.

Comment: Your link for Fluid takes me to a story writing site!

Comment: Dangit! Sorry about that, @jmh. My  MBP keyboard has been on the fritz. Must not have responded when I `⌘C`'d the URL the first time. Fixed.

Comment: I also use Fluid for other apps, but the Google Shortcut solution above is brilliant, and adds the app to the task switcher if you select "Open as Window". Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

I use Sunrise and it's great, you can add your Google Account and the GUI is very similar.

Comment: Sunrise is shutting down: http://blog.sunrise.am/post/144196642739/its-almost-time-to-say-goodbye

Comment: now shut down, as of today after an extension :( :(

Comment: Sunrise was the best calendar app ever. RIP

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want the calendar week to show on your desktop, you will want to check out the program Blotter.  It can be found in the AppleStore.  I have been using it for over a year, very pleased with it.

Answer (score -3):

There are a few new GCal apps on the App Store (all paid though).