# How to find Google Calendar app on my MacBook after downloading with iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, calendar

I would like to download the Google Calendar app on my Mac.

I found Google Calendar in iTunes and clicked on Download. It looks like the app was downloaded, but I can't find it on my Mac.

Here is a screenshot of iTunes

[image: iTunes screenshot]

How I can find this app on my MacBook?

Comment: That description says it's only designed for iPad and iPhone, not the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Store in iTunes is for iOS apps, i.e. iPhone, iPad and iPod touch.

For Mac apps, you can download these from the Mac App Store: the App Store.app in the Applications folder. Mac apps can also be downloaded from anywhere else on the internet.

There is no Google Calendar app made by Google for macOS. You can use the built-in Calendar.app to access your Google Calendar. [Is there a Google Calendar Mac Desktop App?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/236444/37797)